How to get users by rcp level in WordPress?
I have created a plugin where employers are able to search freelancers and hire them. I have added restrict content pro plugin to handle subscription for freelancers. there are 4 levels. level 0 or none is free and I only want the freelancers to show up on results page if they are in level 1, 2 or 3. I have tried the following but no luck.
$freelancers = get_users( [
  'role' => 'fmaa_freelancer',
  'number' => -1,
  'orderby' => 'display_name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'key' => 'rcp_user_level',
    'value' => [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    'compare' => 'IN'
  )
] );

I have also tried the rcp_subscription_level and rcp_user_subscription_level but its not working. I tried to look up for the user meta key in database but no luck. It seems like restrict content pro has its own separate tables.

rcp_get_memberships() allows to query by, among other things, membership level IDs. RCP_Membership has a direct connection to RCP_Customer, and from the latter you can get the actual WP user id.

Use rcp_get_memberships() to get users with specific memberships and store their ids into an array. Then simply query the users of these ids.
// Get only level 1, 2, 3 users
$memberships = rcp_get_memberships( [
  'status' => 'active', // Optional: Only get active memberships
  'object_id' => [ 1, 2, 3 ]
] );

$user_ids = [];

foreach ( $memberships as $membership ) {

  $user_ids[] = $membership->get_user_id();

}

$user_ids = array_unique( $user_ids ); // Removing duplicates if a user has more than one membership

// Get Freelancers
$freelancers = get_users( [
  'include' => $user_ids,
  'role' => 'fmaa_freelancer',
  'number' => $per_page,
  'offset' => ( $page_no - 1 ) * $per_page, // Calculate the offset
  'orderby' => 'display_name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => $meta_query
] );

